# Getting warnings and errors related to the conflicts in dependencies after adding angular-oauth2-oidc dependency in package.json

Tags: angular, npm

I am working on the angular project. My package.json file is given below:

```
{
    "name": "angular.io-example",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "Example project from an angular.io guide.",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
      "start": "ng serve",
      "build": "ng build",
      "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
      "test": "ng test",
      "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "@ag-grid-community/angular": "^26.0.0",
      "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model": "^26.0.0",
      "@ag-grid-community/core": "^26.0.0",
      "@ag-grid-community/infinite-row-model": "^26.0.0",
      "@ag-grid-enterprise/charts": "^26.0.0",
      "@ag-grid-enterprise/core": "^26.0.0",
      "@ag-grid-enterprise/menu": "^26.0.0",
      "@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping": "^26.0.0",
      "@angular/animations": "~12.2.10",
      "@angular/cdk": "~12.2.10",
      "@angular/common": "~12.2.10",
      "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.10",
      "@angular/core": "~12.2.10",
      "@angular/flex-layout": "~12.0.0-beta.35",
      "@angular/forms": "~12.2.10",
      "@angular/material": "~12.2.10",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.10",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.10",
      "@angular/router": "~12.2.10",
      "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
      "@stomp/rx-stomp": "^1.1.4",
      "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.5.0",
      "ajv": "^8.6.3",
      "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^12.1.0",
      "angular-split": "^5.0.0",
      "array-flat-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
      "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
      "core-js": "^3.18.3",
      "lodash": "~4.17.21",
      "mat-progress-buttons": "~9.3.1",
      "material-icons": "^1.10.6",
      "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
      "normalize-path": "^3.0.0",
      "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
      "tslib": "^2.0.0",
      "typeface-roboto": "1.1.13",
      "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
      "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "~12.1.3",
      "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.10",
      "@angular-eslint/builder": "^12.6.0",
      "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^12.6.0",
      "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^12.6.0",
      "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^12.6.0",
      "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^12.6.0",
      "@angular/cli": "~12.2.10",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.10",
      "@angular/language-service": "~12.2.10",
      "@types/fs-extra": "^9.0.13",
      "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
      "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
      "@types/node": "^16.11.1",
      "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.2",
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.2",
      "async": "^3.2.1",
      "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
      "cssnano-preset-default": "~5.1.4",
      "eslint": "^7.26.0",
      "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
      "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^14.0.1",
      "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
      "eslint-plugin-rxjs": "^4.0.0",
      "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
      "https-proxy-agent": "^5.0.0",
      "jasmine-core": "^3.10.0",
      "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
      "karma": "~6.3.4",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
      "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
      "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
      "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
      "karma-sabarivka-reporter": "~3.3.1",
      "karma-typescript": "^5.5.2",
      "ng-mocks": "^13.1.0",
      "ng-packagr": "^12.2.3",
      "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
      "prettier": "^2.4.1",
      "prettier-eslint": "^13.0.0",
      "protractor": "~7.0.0",
      "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
      "ts-node": "~10.3.0",
      "typescript": "~4.3.5",
      "wait-on": "^6.0.0",
      "webpack": "^5.61.0"
    }
  }
```

The problem is that when I add angular-oauth2-oidc dependency and use command npm install, I get errors. I had to use npm install --force command but still I get warnings which are given below

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: eslint-plugin-rxjs@4.0.4
npm WARN Found: eslint@7.32.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint
npm WARN   dev eslint@"^7.26.0" from the root project      
npm WARN   19 more (@angular-eslint/builder, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer eslint@"^8.0.0" from eslint-plugin-rxjs@4.0.4
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-rxjs
npm WARN   dev eslint-plugin-rxjs@"^4.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.24.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint
npm WARN   peer eslint@"^8.0.0" from eslint-plugin-rxjs@4.0.4
npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-plugin-rxjs
npm WARN     dev eslint-plugin-rxjs@"^4.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: mat-progress-buttons@9.3.1
npm WARN Found: @angular/cdk@12.2.13
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm WARN   @angular/cdk@"~12.2.10" from the root project
npm WARN   2 more (@angular/flex-layout, @angular/material)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @angular/cdk@"^11.0.3" from mat-progress-buttons@9.3.1
npm WARN node_modules/mat-progress-buttons
npm WARN   mat-progress-buttons@"~9.3.1" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/cdk@11.2.13
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm WARN   peer @angular/cdk@"^11.0.3" from mat-progress-buttons@9.3.1
npm WARN   node_modules/mat-progress-buttons
npm WARN     mat-progress-buttons@"~9.3.1" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: mat-progress-buttons@9.3.1
npm WARN Found: @angular/common@12.2.16
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/common
npm WARN   @angular/common@"~12.2.10" from the root project
npm WARN   11 more (@ag-grid-community/angular, @angular/cdk, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @angular/common@"^11.0.5" from mat-progress-buttons@9.3.1
npm WARN node_modules/mat-progress-buttons
npm WARN   mat-progress-buttons@"~9.3.1" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@11.2.14
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/common
npm WARN   peer @angular/common@"^11.0.5" from mat-progress-buttons@9.3.1
npm WARN   node_modules/mat-progress-buttons
npm WARN     mat-progress-buttons@"~9.3.1" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: mat-progress-buttons@9.3.1
npm WARN Found: @angular/core@12.2.16
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/core
npm WARN   @angular/core@"~12.2.10" from the root project
npm WARN   13 more (@ag-grid-community/angular, @angular/animations, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @angular/core@"^11.0.5" from mat-progress-buttons@9.3.1
npm WARN node_modules/mat-progress-buttons
npm WARN   mat-progress-buttons@"~9.3.1" from the root project
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@11.2.14
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/core
npm WARN   peer @angular/core@"^11.0.5" from mat-progress-buttons@9.3.1
npm WARN   node_modules/mat-progress-buttons
npm WARN     mat-progress-buttons@"~9.3.1" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: mat-progress-buttons@9.3.1
npm WARN Found: @angular/material@12.2.13
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/material
npm WARN   @angular/material@"~12.2.10" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @angular/material@"^11.0.3" from mat-progress-buttons@9.3.1
npm WARN node_modules/mat-progress-buttons
npm WARN   mat-progress-buttons@"~9.3.1" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/material@11.2.13
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/material
npm WARN   peer @angular/material@"^11.0.3" from mat-progress-buttons@9.3.1
npm WARN   node_modules/mat-progress-buttons
npm WARN     mat-progress-buttons@"~9.3.1" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: eslint-etc@5.2.0
npm WARN Found: eslint@7.32.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint
npm WARN   dev eslint@"^7.26.0" from the root project
npm WARN   19 more (@angular-eslint/builder, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer eslint@"^8.0.0" from eslint-etc@5.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-rxjs/node_modules/eslint-etc
npm WARN   eslint-etc@"^5.1.0" from eslint-plugin-rxjs@4.0.4
npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-plugin-rxjs
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.24.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint
npm WARN   peer eslint@"^8.0.0" from eslint-etc@5.2.0
npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-plugin-rxjs/node_modules/eslint-etc
npm WARN     eslint-etc@"^5.1.0" from eslint-plugin-rxjs@4.0.4
npm WARN     node_modules/eslint-plugin-rxjs

up to date, audited 1899 packages in 8s

173 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

10 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 4 high)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

If I use command npm list for any dependency for which I am getting warnings, for example if I type command npm list @angular/core I am getting these errors

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

├─┬ @ag-grid-community/angular@26.2.0
│ └── @angular/core@12.2.16 deduped
├─┬ @angular/animations@12.2.16
│ └── @angular/core@12.2.16 deduped
├─┬ @angular/cdk@12.2.13
│ └── @angular/core@12.2.16 deduped
├─┬ @angular/common@12.2.16
│ └── @angular/core@12.2.16 deduped
├── @angular/core@12.2.16
├─┬ @angular/flex-layout@12.0.0-beta.35
│ └── @angular/core@12.2.16 deduped
├─┬ @angular/forms@12.2.16
│ └── @angular/core@12.2.16 deduped
├─┬ @angular/material@12.2.13
│ └── @angular/core@12.2.16 deduped
├─┬ @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@12.2.16
│ └── @angular/core@12.2.16 deduped
├─┬ @angular/platform-browser@12.2.16
│ └── @angular/core@12.2.16 deduped
├─┬ @angular/router@12.2.16
│ └── @angular/core@12.2.16 deduped
├─┬ angular-oauth2-oidc@12.1.0
│ └── @angular/core@12.2.16 deduped
├─┬ angular-split@5.0.0
│ └── @angular/core@12.2.16 deduped
├─┬ codelyzer@6.0.2
│ └── @angular/core@9.0.0
├─┬ mat-progress-buttons@9.3.1
│ └── @angular/core@12.2.16 deduped invalid: "^11.0.5" from node_modules/mat-progress-buttons
└─┬ ng-mocks@13.5.2
  └── @angular/core@12.2.16 deduped invalid: "^11.0.5" from node_modules/mat-progress-buttons

npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: @angular/core@12.2.16 C:\Users\usajid\Desktop\testapp\node_modules\@angular\core

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\usajid\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-28T08_41_27_599Z-debug-0.log
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit brutal, but after fighting with similar dependency issues for a while, removing all the npm information from the project and reinstalling fixed it for me.

Use with caution, but removing these files will force npm to start from scratch when installing packages:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf .npm
rm package-lock.json
```

From there you should be able to run `npm install` to get a fresh set of packages installed and hopefully have no dependency conflicts.

Comment: still facing the same issue. still i had to use npm install --force and still warnings were coming.

Comment: Also I am getting other errors like Unable to import class BrowserModule.
  The module '@angular/platform-browser' could not be found.